# Change z-index for the clicked button relative to the wanted section

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a parallax JavaScript code with 5 sections (with class background), each section 1 image + text with a content wrapper.

They actually have the following z-index::

```css
.background:nth-child(1) { z-index: 5; }

.background:nth-child(2) { z-index: 4; }

.background:nth-child(3) { z-index: 3; }

.background:nth-child(4) { z-index: 2; }

.background:nth-child(5) { z-index: 1; }
```

```js
var currentSlideNumber = 0;
```

(Will tell which slide I'm at so I can make transitions in the left-menu, and with scroll.)

And I also have, a left-menu fixed to chose where do I want to go without having to scroll through the sections, my problem is that I can't make the higher sections show after being in a lower one ( I'm in `.background:nth-child(1)`, I can't make it show the `.background:nth-child(5)` but has I have the `z-index` higher in the 1st it just sits behind it)

Any ideas how I should code so that I can get and higher `z-index` in the (for example) 5th comparing to the 1st but also if I get back clicking at the first the `z-index` would return to normal.

I want it to be capable of showing the slide with `z-index` when called from the left-menu.

Any ideas how can I do it?

Comment: can you post your markup? or create a fiddle with the issue?

Answer (score 0):

When you show a slide by clicking an option in the menu, you can apply a `slide-active` class to the respective slide. You'll also need to remove this class from any previously active slides:

```
document.querySelector('.slide-active').classList.remove('slide-active')

// Assumes currentSlideNumber is an array index, ie 0 - (n - 1). Otherwise use currentSlideNumber - 1
document.querySelectorAll('.background')[currentSlideNumber].classList.add('slide-active')
```

And the CSS:

```
.slide-active {
    z-index: 999
}
```

In this way, you can remove unique `z-index` from each slide and just DOM ordering to have the top slide to show by default (i.e. placing it last in the markup).